Continuation of the “Lorenzified” Riemann zeta $\zeta_{L}(x)$?
I have been studying a particular function that might be described as, the “Lorenz curve of the Riemann zeta function,” and I am curious about its possible analytic continuation to the complex plane. I will not formally discuss the Lorenz curve but I would like say that it is a tool widely used in economics and my definition incorporates its structure. I suggest the Lorenzified zeta function has a representation as:
$$ \zeta_{L}(x) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\int_0^x \sum_{n=1}^k e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(t)}} \, dt}{\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^k e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(t)}} \, dt} $$
We can note that $\zeta_{L}(0)=0,$ $\zeta_{L}(1)=1$ and that $0\le\zeta_{L}(x)\le1$ and that this function is strictly increasing.
I would like to understand if this function $ \zeta_{L}(x) $ can be analytically continued to the complex plane. Specifically, I am interested in the following:

Is there a natural way to maximally (or even partially) extend $ \zeta_{L}(x) $ to a function $ \zeta_{L}(z) $ where $ z \in \mathbb{C} $?

It has been difficult (for me at least) to access the function due to the way it is defined. Hopefully somebody can see something I am missing. Oftentimes an integral is a platform that can be used to easily continue a function to $\Bbb C$, but I don't see how to do that yet with this function i.e. which contour to use.
As a alluded to above, I find this function particularly intriguing because it appears to be precisely the Lorenz curve associated to the Riemann zeta function. This suggests that the function might have interesting properties and structures when considered in the context of complex analysis. I would like to point out that $\zeta_{L}(x)$ may not be related to the Riemman zeta function at all. However I am curious if some properties from the zeta function do carry over, and I am mostly interested in a maximal or partial extension to the complex plane therein.
This is just to note the connection that:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(x)}} $$
is the Riemann zeta composed with $-1/\ln(x)$.
Any insights, references, or detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated!
